# div problem in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css

**strong text**

i am using asp.net in visual studio 2005

how can i put my controls from toolbox any where i want in my aspx page

it does moves freely as in windows application

plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work like that I'm afraid, not for ASP.NET web applications nor any web application that uses **[HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Html)** for its markup language for that matter. This must be achieved with proper semantic HTML and **[CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets)**.